# Create multiple onclick events inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons with the ids `"especifica-i-pj"`, where i goes from 1 to 4 and j goes from 1 to 3. The idea is to assign an `onclick` event to each one of them, without having to declare 12 functions. I thought this would solve my problem:

```js
for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 1; j <= 3; j++ ) {
        dom_id = "especifica-"+i.toString()+"-p"+j.toString();
        document.getElementById(dom_id).onclick = function() {
            console.log("you clicked ",dom_id)
            ponder[i-1] = 0.1 + 0.05*(j-1);
            console.log("ponder:",i,ponder[i-1])
            $("#"+dom_id).addClass("active");
            for ( k = 1; k <= 3 && k != j; k++ )
                $("#especifica-"+i.toString()+"-p"+k.toString()).removeClass("active");
        }
    }
}
```

However each time I click any of the buttons, my console outputs that I clicked `especifica-4-p3`, the last one, and outputs `ponder: 5 0.25`, when `i==5` should not be possible, as the outer for gets to `i==4`.

What can I do to make this work? I have been searching online but I have not found anything about this, or even declaring functions inside for loops. Thanks.

Comment: No, i gets to 5, and then exits the for loop.  It is still 5 at the time of the click event.  You likely want to store the current value of i into a different non-global variable so that you can reference it inside your function.

Comment: What does your `HTML` look like? I'd be helpful to see that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to do one of the following:

1. Store the values of i and j on the DOM element.
2. Parse the clicked id to get the values of i and j.
3. Assign the values of i and j to non-global variables so that you can retrieve them later.

Method 1:

```
for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  for(j=1; j<=3; j++) {
    dom_id = "especifica-"+i.toString()+"-p"+j.toString();
    element = document.getElementById(dom_id);
    element.i = i;
    element.j = j;
    element.onclick = function() {
      console.log("you clicked ",dom_id)
      ponder[this.i-1] = 0.1 + 0.05*(this.j-1);
      console.log("ponder:",this.i,ponder[this.i-1])
      $("#"+dom_id).addClass("active");
      for(k=1; k<=3 && k!=j; k++)
        $("#especifica-"+this.i.toString()+"-p"+k.toString()).removeClass("active");
    }
  }
}
```

Method 2:

```
for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  for(j=1; j<=3; j++) {
    dom_id = "especifica-"+i.toString()+"-p"+j.toString();
    document.getElementById(dom_id).onclick = function() {
      i = dom_id.substring(11,12);
      j = dom_id.substring(14,15);
      console.log("you clicked ",dom_id)
      ponder[i-1] = 0.1 + 0.05*(j-1);
      console.log("ponder:",i,ponder[i-1])
      $("#"+dom_id).addClass("active");
      for(k=1; k<=3 && k!=j; k++)
        $("#especifica-"+i.toString()+"-p"+k.toString()).removeClass("active");
    }
  }
}
```

Method 3:

```
for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  let i1 = i;
  for(j=1; j<=3; j++) {
    let j1 = j;
    dom_id = "especifica-"+i.toString()+"-p"+j.toString();
    document.getElementById(dom_id).onclick = function() {
      console.log("you clicked ",dom_id)
      ponder[i1-1] = 0.1 + 0.05*(j1-1);
      console.log("ponder:",i,ponder[i1-1])
      $("#"+dom_id).addClass("active");
      for(k=1; k<=3 && k!=j; k++)
        $("#especifica-"+i1.toString()+"-p"+k.toString()).removeClass("active");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I do 1)?

Comment: Could you show me howto? I've been searching and found nothing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also make a local function and call it, which would be yet another way.  I suspect that you could also use the position of the elements to determine i and j and use a single event handler, but we'd need to see the html to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to capture on click for the first level parent which is the parent for all the buttons,

Only for that you create on click,

inside the event function detect `event.target` which will tell from which button the click is happening

```js
function buttonClick(event) {
    alert(event.target.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onclick="buttonClick(event)">
   <button id="especifica-1-p1">b11</button>
   <button id="especifica-1-p2">b12</button>
   <button id="especifica-1-p3">b13</button>
   <button id="especifica-2-p1">b21</button>
   <button id="especifica-2-p2">b22</button>
   <button id="especifica-2-p3">b23</button>
</div>
```

If you want to maintain the data `1,1`  `1,2` ... etc , you can do like this

In each button you can introduce dummy data attributes with your own name assumption

Example

```
<button id="especifica-1-p1" data-row="1" data-column="1">b11</button>
<button id="especifica-1-p2" data-row="1" data-column="2">b12</button>
```

Then you can use JavaScript

```
event.target.getAttribute("data-row");
event.target.getAttribute("data-column");
```

Comment: Thanks! I will use this too! hehe :·3

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix by using `data-*` attributes:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    var buttonId = "especifica-" + i + "-p" + j;
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    
    button.setAttribute("data-i", i);
    button.setAttribute("data-j", j);

    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("i", event.target.getAttribute("data-i"));
      console.log("j", event.target.getAttribute("data-j"));
      console.log("button with id of", event.target.id, "was clicked!");
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button id="especifica-1-p1" type="button">especifica-1-p1</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-1-p2" type="button">especifica-1-p2</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-1-p3" type="button">especifica-1-p3</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-2-p1" type="button">especifica-2-p1</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-2-p2" type="button">especifica-2-p2</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-2-p3" type="button">especifica-2-p3</button></div>
```

Learn more about `data-*` attributes here:

- [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

---

Alternatively, you could take advantage of the concept of `closures`, like in the following example:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    var buttonId = "especifica-" + i + "-p" + j;
    var button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    
    var createEventListener = function (iValue, jValue) {
      return function (event) {
        console.log("i:", iValue, "j:", jValue);
        console.log("button with id of", event.target.id, "was clicked!");
      }
    };
    button.addEventListener("click", createEventListener(i, j));
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button id="especifica-1-p1" type="button">especifica-1-p1</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-1-p2" type="button">especifica-1-p2</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-1-p3" type="button">especifica-1-p3</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-2-p1" type="button">especifica-2-p1</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-2-p2" type="button">especifica-2-p2</button></div>
<div><button id="especifica-2-p3" type="button">especifica-2-p3</button></div>
```

Read more about `closures` here:

- [Variable scope](https://javascript.info/closure)

Also, use the `element.addEventListener` method instead of `element.onclick`. Have a look at here why it's better to use `addEventListener('click', ...)` instead of `onclick`:

- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/5862900)

Comment: how can I use the i, j values inside the function without parsing the string?

Comment: @mianfg If you're talking about having access to `i` and `j` inside of the event handler, then they're both in the scope of that handler function, so you can just use them however you'd like. See my edit.

Comment: @goto1 Change your `var i` to `let i` and `var j` to `let j` to fix it so you can reference the current value of i and j inside the function.